# Run NiFi on a linux machine

Tags: apache-nifi

I just downloaded nifi-0.5.1 for linux.

When trying to run Nifi using the command: `./nifi.sh run`

I get the following exception in `nifi-app.log`:

> 2016-03-13 05:29:42,959 WARN [main]
>   org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server...
>   shutting down. org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start
>   Flow Controller.
>           at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:99)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
>   ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
>           at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:663)
>   ~[nifi-jetty-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:137) [nifi-runtime-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:227) [nifi-runtime-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1] Caused by:
>   java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   ./flowfile_repository/partition-61/2.journal: Too many open files
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:380)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:106) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
>           at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.createDataInputStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:932)
>   ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getRecoveryStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:947)
>   ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getNextRecoverableTransactionId(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:973)
>   ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromEdits(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:419)
>   ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:293)
>   ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.loadFlowFiles(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:323)
>   ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.initializeFlow(FlowController.java:609)
>   ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:641)
>   ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:479)
>   ~[nifi-framework-core-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
>           at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:79)
>   ~[na:na]
>           ... 22 common frames omitted 2016-03-13 05:29:42,961 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web
>   server...

I would appreciate your help,

Comment: It looks like `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./flowfile_repository/partition-61/2.journal: Too many open files` is the origin exception.  Is this the first time NiFi has started, or was it running before?

Comment: it was first time that i started NiFi on this machine. updating limits.conf file solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

By default NiFi accesses quite a lot of files at startup due to its classloader isolation approach and its function as a dataflow app.  Please see the administration guide where it describes how to set the OS limit on number of open file handles higher.  The default OS file handle limit in linux is usually 1024 and this is quite a ways too low for what NiFi does.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices

Comment: Thanks Joe, it solved the problem. I saw this section in the guide, but thought that these are "nice to have" (but not must) definitions

Comment: yeah that is a fair opinion.  It honestly used to be a nice to have but overtime has moved into must have :-)